# Ember 1.11.0-beta "A block may only be used inside an HTML element or another block" error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to load some remote templates using 1.11 beta 4 and am running into an error when ember-template-compiler tried to compile the template.  It throws the "A block may only be used inside an HTML element or another block" exception.  I am compiling the template with:

```
var compiledTemplate = Ember.Handlebars.compile(templateText);
```

Has anyone seen this before?  The template is:

```
<p{{#id}} id="{{id}}"{{/id}} data-name="{{name}}" class="flag {{#alert}}{{type}} {{type}}-input{{/alert}} {{styleClass}}{{^alert}} hide{{/alert}}">
  <span{{#id}} id="{{alertSevId}}"{{/id}} class="alertSeverity icon">
    {{#alert}}{{type}}{{/alert}}
  </span>
  <span{{#id}} id="{{alertMsgId}}"{{/id}} class="alertMessage">
    {{#alert}}{{message}}{{/alert}}
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: What are all these blocks `{{#id}}`, `{{#alert}}` etc.. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: The example is a Mustache template.  I'm trying to evaluate how much rework is involved in adopting Ember since our existing templates are Mustache and not Handlebars.  Since they are very similar I figured I'd try, but I wasn't expecting this error.  But it might just be the default if it doesn't understand something in the input string.

Answer (score 6):

I am learning Ember and I was stuck on the same error message today, `"Error: A block may only be used inside an HTML element or another block."`

I am using Ember v1.10, however.

I was working through a tutorial, and commented out a portion of my HTML so I could try something else:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="logs">
    <section>
        <ul>
            {{#each log in model}}
            <li>{{log.name}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>

       <!--<ul>-->
       <!--{{#each dev in controller}}-->
       <!--<li>{{dev}}</li>-->
       <!--{{/each}}-->
       <!--</ul>-->
       <!--<button {{action "clickMe"}}Click me!</button>-->
       <!--<p>{{renderedOn}}</p>-->
    </section>
</script>
```

When I attempted to view the new changes nothing was displaying. I was convinced it was because of the new unordered list I added or maybe changes I made to my JavaScript, but the source of my error was the commented out HTML.  I removed it and everything functioned as expected.

I tinkered around with this situation some more and I observed:

- If I commented it out the portion of code with a block statement, instead of a line comment works as expected
- If I left the first line of commented out code and removed the others, it works as expected

So then, through the process of elimination I found the culprit was commenting out the each helper:

```
   <!--{{#each dev in controller}}-->
   <!--{{/each}}-->
```

I know this is not quite the same setup as yours, but hopefully it can point you in the right direction for solving your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add a "block" which is denoted as "#" inside a tag. Which is invalid. Try removing the "#" from `{{#id ...}}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to conditionally set an html attribute if it is defined.  To accomplish this you could translate this mustache:
`<div {{#id}}id="{{id}}" {{/id}}>`
...into this Ember hbs template (notice the lack of quotes around {{id}}):
`<div id={{id}}>`
You will achieve the same result:
id has been set - `<div id="foo">`
id has not been set - `<div >`
Avoids this undesired result - `<div id="">`